# it is & there are

Tags: word-choice

Can we use there are instead of it is in this sentence? It is three kilometres from here to the station. Can we say "There are three kilometres from here to the station"?
thanks in avance

Comment: No, we cannot. 'It' is understood to mean 'It is a distance of three kilometres', and we think of distance as a singular noun.

Answer (score 1):

**Both are valid**, but their usage is different, e.g.

- It's three kilometres from here to the station.  There's a bus every five minutes, so you'll make the train, no problem.
- There are three kilometres from here to the train station.  It's the first part of the 10k course and pretty much the easiest.  The third kilometre is on a narrow path through the park, but the runners should be well spaced out by then.

Generally speaking, you'd use the second form only if you wanted to say something specific about one or more of the kilometres.  If you're talking about the distance in general, **it is** would be the best form to use.